# hstore_translate existing data migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, hstore, globalize3

I've added [hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) to a Rails4 project with existing data.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :subtitle, :description
end

config.i18n.fallbacks = true

class AddTranslationColumnsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :subtitle_translations, :hstore
    add_column :products, :description_translations,  :hstore
  end
end
```

How can I access my old subtitle and description fields? Because now Post.subtitle and Post.description always nil. Fallback doesn't work or I need migrate data first?

**upd**:

This migration solves problem.

```
class MigrateExistingDataToTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute "UPDATE products p SET subtitle_translations=hstore('en',(select subtitle from products where id = p.id));"
    execute "UPDATE products p SET description_translations=hstore('en', (select description from products where id = p.id));"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) defines methods to read the various translations.

When defining `translates :subtitle, :description`, the methods `subtitle` & `description` are created, which gets the fitting translation. So when calling `Product.subtitle`, instead of getting the column and its data it is calling the method.

To access the data temporarily you should comment out the [hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) setup

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # translates :subtitle, :description
end
```

Then merge your data to the new columns before uncommenting again.